# Apache SOLR and string range search

Tags: java, string, search, solr, lucene

Is possible to search by range on field type 'string'?

```
fieldString:[A TO B]
```

or

```
fieldString:[U-00* TO U-009]
```

mean that give result with fields where all characters sequences are between A to B or 
all U-000 between U-009

Now I got some few field with values from U-001, U-002... to U-009

```
I try: fieldString:[U-00* TO U-009] but this dont work
fieldString:/U-00[0-9]/ and also the same non results
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But the results may depend on how you analyzed the string in the index. If the string is just A or B, there is no problem; but on some tokenizing you may get all results containing A or B.

```
schema.xml:
<types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
    ...
</types>

<fields>
    ...
    <field name="isbn" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    ...
</fields>

solrconfig.xml:
<requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="standard">
</requestHandler>
```

As you see, there is nothing special. String type is not treated by any filters, but just stored as is. And I use the standard query parser. In this configuration your example works

Comment: How I can check this ?

Comment: Have a look at the fieldType of the field in question in the schema.xml. There are the analyzers (tokenizers, filters) defined. Possibly for your concern you will want to work with pure strings.

Comment: <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

Comment: I just check and got analyzer on this field:

<analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

Comment: The standard tokenizer splits on whitespace, and the lower case filter does, what its name says... Did you try, if the range search works for your case? Is there any problem, or do you inquire just theoretically?

Comment: Exacly I need this : title:[Aida TO Carmen]
'This will find all documents whose titles are between Aida and Carmen, including Aida and Carmen.' 
But in my example where I want take string from ["U-000".* TO .*"09"] just results nothing; also I try search for ["DOCUMENT-001 Z" TO "009 Z"] but got parse exception I think exception is from whiteSpace; 
I need results which give me back U-0001, U-0002, U-0003... to U-0009 or DOCUMENT-001 Z, DOCUMENT-002 Z ... to DOCUMENT-009 Z

Comment: Which query parser do you use? I tried that with the standard parser on one of my own indexes and it worked. `fq:isbn:[97831* TO 97833*]`Perhaps you should show more of your schema and solrconfig.

Comment: What exacly do You need from config ? all ? sometimes you do not use for this filedType as number/integer ? then everything works ok, I need this for fieldType string

Comment: I have added the significant parts to my answer.

Comment: OK, I will check this in middle of the week and give the answer :)

Comment: Hello again, I'm little disappointed, in my case this won't work :|
my field is a type textField and tokenized as I post before and there is no easy way to take some data by example: ['U-001' TO '*9$'] - every from U-001 .... TO U-009

Comment: Either you can choose a data type for this field which is not tokenized, or if this is not possible, you can copy the field into another, which is not tokenized, and use this for querying.

Comment: How can copy dynamicFields ? under is my data about this field
<dynamicField name="*_STRING"  type="toke_string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

Comment: @PDS If you know solution for your question, Please share with us